# How to upload image to windows form Gridview cell using devexperess?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I am developing windows from an application using devexpress and I need to add images to gridview cell, I have tried many things but I am not able to do it. Please help me anyone how to resolve this issue. I have given below my code

```
private void rptBtnupload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();
        opf.Filter = "Choose Image(*.jpg;*.png;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif";

        if (opf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName);
        }

        pictureBox1.Image = (Image)gridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value;

    }
```

I am getting Error Like
'DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: There seems to be a lot of confusion.
In the question you say you need to insert an image on a cell, but from the code do the opposite, you're trying to retrieve an image from a cell.

Comment: this is Just am trying codes, really i dont know how to do it. I need to upload image to the gridview cell

Comment: To get a cell value, you can use the GridView.GetRowCellValue method. However, this will return you a value, but not set it.  If you need to pass an image to a cell, use the GridView.SetRowCellValue method.

Comment: I have tried like  pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
            byte[] img = ms.ToArray();
            gridView1.SetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["Images"], img);

Comment: Is your GridControl bound to a data source, such as a DataTable or List<T>?  If so, what is the data type of the "Images" column?

Comment: I find out the Solution thank you your support

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access a cell value, use the [GridView.GetRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.GetRowCellValue.overloads) method.
Please refer to the [Obtaining and Setting Cell Values](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/753/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Data-Editing/Editing-via-Code/Obtaining-and-Setting-Cell-Values) help article for more information.